# Can't connect to database on my website created by using wamp

Tags: mysql, database, wamp

I installed wamp, make it run, logged in http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/ and created a database called: "automobile". I made my own website and it's working. But when I want to use my database, I can't.
I have this error:

**Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\connect.php on line 8**

This is my file that is supposed to connect me to my database.

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $passw = "root";
    $db = "automobile";

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $passw, $db);

    // Verificarea conexiunii
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Problema la conectare la baza de date " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    else {
        //echo "Conectare cu succes la baza de date <br>";
    }
?>
```

And here is config.inc file from WAMP:

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
 *
 * All directives are explained in documentation in the doc/ folder
 * or at <http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'a8b7c6d'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 3307;



/*
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

// No warning on  pmadb tables
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;


?>
```

Comment: Try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: I tried. Not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your database has a password? If you not set a pass for the db you will not connect with one.

If you are using localhost to develop i think that you don't need, not now. You can just connect without put the password variable. Or you can go to you db manager, like phpMyAdmin or mysql workbench and set you password.

Maybe a blank password, like `$passw = "";`

Comment: No. How do I set pass for database?

Comment: I think it may be because I changed the port in 3307 and he is using port 3306 by default. But in this case, I don't know what to write to enter on this port instead of the default one.